# How to format Surface pro 4 encrypted with Bitlocker?

Tags: windows-10, boot, encryption, bitlocker, microsoft-surface

my surface pro 4 is encrypted with bitlocker and I dont now the password and can not get it....

So if I want to boot from a USB stick, the boot process will be blocked and the bitlocker screen appears.

How can I format it ?